# Event not getting removed from window

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I am having hard time removing event from window and I am not able to figure out why is it not working. 
I have a function in which I am adding an event to window.

```
Test.prototype.func1 = function(){
    this.func2 = function(){
      // do something
    };

    window.addEventListener("event1", this.func2, true);
};
```

Now I have an `exit` function (which is called when I exit that particular tab), from where I am calling `detachEvent()`, in which I am removing my event from window.

```
Test.prototype.exit = function(){
    this.detachEvent();
}
```

And my `detachEvent` function is

```
Test.prototype.detachEvent() = function(){
    window.removeEventListener("event1", this.func2, true);
}
```

Now the problem arises because my code is part of a larger project and somehow `func1` is being called twice. So `event1` is being added twice to window.
So to not have duplicate event I even tried calling `detachEvent()` before adding event to window like

```
Test.prototype.func1 = function(){
    this.func2 = function(){
      // do something
    }
    this.detachEvent();
    window.addEventListener("event1", this.func2, true);
}
```

But the event is not getting removed when `detachEvent()` is getting called from inside `func1()`, but it is working when `detachEvent()` is getting called from exit().

My code works in cases where event is not added twice but here its not working.
I am not able to figure out the reason and any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code I can see the problem is '**this.func2**' is assigned inside '**Test.prototype.func1**' so when you call function '**func1**' again and again it just re-assigning '**func2**' again and again. The best way to fix this issue is,

**func1**

```
Test.prototype.func1 = function(){
  this.detachEvent();
  window.addEventListener("event1", this.func2, true);
}
```

**exit**

```
Test.prototype.exit = function(){
       this.detachEvent();
}
```

**detachEvent**

```
Test.prototype.detachEvent = function(){
    window.removeEventListener("event1", this.func2, true);
}
```

**func2**

```
Test.prototype.func2 = function(){
     // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the old `func2` handler. You've already overwritten it when you're calling `detachEvent` from `func1`, so it tries to remove a function that was never installed, without affecting the event handler.

```
Test.prototype.func1 = function() {
  this.detachEvent(); // move here!
  this.func2 = function(){ … };
  window.addEventListener("event1", this.func2, true);
}
```

Alternatively, don't assign `func2` inside `func1`, but initialise the property once in the constructor (or even make it a prototype method). That way, `addEventListener` even won't register the *same* function twice.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the event to be added a single time you need to set a flag to prevent it from being added again.  Something like.

```
Test.prototype.func1 = function(){
  if (this._func2added) return;
  this._func2added = true;

  this.func2 = function(){
     // do something
  }

  window.addEventListener("event1", this.func2, true);
}
```

And on your detach release the flag on that.

Comment: Hi @Austio, This makes the thing work. Thank you for the suggestion. But this is a kind of work around for the issue. But i was wondering why exactly first time i am calling detachEvent(), the event is not getting removed. That is the disease. But thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

change the listener to you action:

old:

```
youobject.addeventListener('something',unknownfunction);
```

use this is better:

```
youobject.event1 = function {
    //you code here
}
```

this automatically clear and set the listener.